# CSS / Javascript - Does "display:none" remove any associated event listeners temporarily?

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener

I'm thinking more in terms of efficiency. If I choose to set the display of an element to `none`, will javascript continue to listen for events attached to it, or does it temporarily remove them until the display is reverted back?

Comment: It doesn't remove the event listeners, but the user can't invoke the events when the element is hidden, although you can still trigger the events from the code

Comment: Depends on the kind of events you are talking about.

Comment: In terms of my own code, they are mainly click or mouseover events.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on the kind of events happening. Let's try using a `click` event:

```js
$(function () {
  // Let's attach an event.
  $("#eventContainer").click(function () {
    $("#eventAffected").html("I changed.");
  });
  // This will hide the container surely when you click.
  $("#hide-container").click(function () {
    $("#eventContainer").hide().css("display", "none");
  });
  // This will trigger the event on the element.
  $("#trigger-event").click(function () {
    $("#eventContainer").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 5px;}
#eventContainer, #eventAffected {background-color: #ccf; text-align: center; padding: 5px;}
#eventAffected {background-color: #cfc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="eventContainer">Hello I am the Event Box</div>
<div id="eventAffected">Hello, I change when event triggered on the above.</div>
<button id="hide-container">Hide</button>
<button id="trigger-event">Trigger Click</button>
```

**Test Cases**

1. **Click on the First Div.** *Second Div Changes, event is triggered.*
2. **Click on the Trigger Click.** *Second Div Changes, event is triggered.*
3. **Click on the Hide and Trigger Click.** *Second Div Changes, event is triggered.*

**Conclusion**

Whether or not, the DOM element is visible in the screen or off-screen, all the events and behaviours are preserved. Only the CSS display is changed. Nothing else, nothing related to behaviour is affected.

This is similar to all the events, only thing is, you **cannot** calculate the dimensions or box model.

So this shows that the events are preserved when there's `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`.

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation. Directing to Quentin's answer, even if events aren't removed, am I correct in saying that the browser will stop testing for them when the element isn't being displayed?

Comment: Technically it will be checked and triggered. But you will not be able to see. I don't know how is Quentin gonna prove it, but this is my view. `:)`

Comment: I have some example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ohad/2L46tego) . you can see that the event that set to the display none element is been triggered

Comment: This is such a nice answer. It explains in a easy way how the event will also still propagate even if the element is hidden in the DOM. I had the same question, needed to activate a hidden button in the DOM in a specific event.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't remove them, but since the element and all of its descendants aren't rendered, there is no way for the user to trigger an event on any of them, so the browser will never test the element to see if it has any event handlers.