# null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('logout-form').submit') - Why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, null

I'm setting up authentication in my Laravel app, I can login and authenticate without issue, but when I click the logout link nothing happens. I am not redirected, I just get this JavaScript error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.getElementById('logout-form').submit')

I've tested in Safari and Chrome and the behaviour is identical. I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, and I'm not a professional developer.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">@csrf</form>
```

I'm not clear on why this is not triggering. Help?

Comment: Must you use a `POST` logout route? Why not `GET`? Then you can just `{{ route('logout') }}` in the anchor href

Comment: I hope below link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970943/css-javascript-does-displaynone-remove-any-associated-event-listeners-tem

Comment: I believe it needs to use post for CSRF token that will be generated by Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.forms` and then access it by its `index` if you have multiple forms and then trigger the submit.