# What is best practice regarding 'mouse' EventListeners and mobile users?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an event listener on a navigation that will get `display:none` on mobile screens. The event listener will still be applied, even though the elements are not displayed.

What is good practice here?

1. Ignore it, this is not a performance issue
2. Check the CSS property if element is displayed or check viewport size, and add conditional around addEventListner. e.g. `getComputedStyle(nav.getPropertyValue('display') !== 'none'`  or `window.width < 1040`
3. Check for matchMedia has hover `window.matchMedia('(hover: hover)').matches // true | false` (does this work for pencils with hover?)
4. Something else?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33971082/16688813).

Comment: @Tom This one talks about if event listeners are applied to display:none. They are, so my question is, what is a nice way to prevent that? 2 and 3 are options but maybe not the nicest way.